Out-of-phase exponential integral of cosine and double-angle cosine
I am trying to solve the following integral:
$${\frac {1}{2\pi }}\int _{0}^{2\pi }e^{z\cos(2\theta )+y\cos (\theta+\theta_0) }d\theta$$
This is similar to this fairly standard integral that can be solved by employing the Jacobi-Anger expansion (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Recurrence_relations):
$${\frac {1}{2\pi }}\int _{0}^{2\pi }e^{z\cos(2\theta )+y\cos \theta }d\theta =I_{0}(z)I_{0}(y)+2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }I_{n}(z)I_{2n}(y)$$
It seems like that phase offset in my integral messes this up considerably. I tried splitting up $\cos (\theta+\theta_0)$ with trigonometric addition formulas, which effectively results in an integral of the form:
$${\frac {1}{2\pi }}\int _{0}^{2\pi }e^{z\cos(2\theta )+y\cos \theta_0 \cos\theta - y\sin \theta_0 \sin\theta}d\theta$$
So now I have 3 terms, which I can replace with their Jacobi-Anger expansions, but now I have a plethora of terms instead of the single infinite sum of the in-phase example above ($y_1=y\cos \theta_0$, $y_2=- y\sin \theta_0$):
$$I_0(y_2) I_0(y_1) I_0(z) + 2 I_0(y_2) \sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n(z) I_{2n}(y_1) + 2 I_0(z) \sum_{n=1}^\infty I_{2n}(y_1) I_{2n}(y_2) (-1)^n + 2 I_0(y_1) \sum_{n=1}^\infty I_{n}(z) I_{2n}(y_2) (-1)^n +  2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty I_{2n}(z) I_{2n}(y_1) I_{2n}(y_2) (-1)^n + 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty I_{n}(z) I_{4n}(y_1) I_{2n}(y_2) (-1)^n + 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty I_{n}(z) I_{2n}(y_1) I_{4n}(y_2)$$
To make matters worse, it seems like the resulting series has terms with alternating signs that nearly cancel out, so it's practically impossible to numerically evaluate this for $z$ and/or $y$ larger than about 10.
Is there a better way to approach this integral? Or is there any way to simplify the resulting sums of products of Bessel functions?

for large z,y you can probably do a saddle point

@user619894 can you elaborate on what a saddle point means in this context?

I mean, expand around the peak(s?) of $z\cos(2\theta)+y\cos(\theta+\theta+0)$, In the limit of large $z,y$ the integral becomes an Gaussian around the peak. See this wikipedia article

Write $\cos\theta=\frac{x+x^{-1}}2$, $\sin\theta=\frac{x-x^{-1}}{2i}$, where $x=e^{i\theta}$ and then use the Residual theory.

@user619894Thank you, that works really well! And with a higher order Laplace method I found here it covers the region where the above series fails

@xpaul I'll give that a try as well, thanks!
